# Is there a better way for me to loop through json nodes in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, foreach, nested-loops

I am wondering if someone could help me and make a suggestion.

I have a JSON file as seen below that contains a few different nodes, I have removed the values for confidentiality purposes. I need to be able to loop through each test step as provided by the JSON and pull the tests that have a step with a status of failed.

So far the easiest way I have found of doing this is nesting for each loop's (Report-> Description-> Element-> Step-> Result-> Status) I am wondering if there are any PowerShell Gurus that can assist me in finding a possible cleaner and faster solution for this?

```
[
  {
    "description": "",
    "elements": [
      {
        "description": "",
        "id": "",
        "keyword": "Scenario",
        "line": 9,
        "name": "",
        "tags": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "line": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "line": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "line": 1
          }
        ],
        "steps": [
          {
            "keyword": "Given ",
            "line": 0,
            "match": {
              "location": ""
            },
            "name": "",
            "result": {
              "duration": 41560.8294,
              "error_message": null,
              "status": "Failed"
            }
          }
        ],
    "name": "",
    "uri": ""
  },
  {
    "description": "",
    "elements": [
      {
        "description": "",
        "id": "",
        "keyword": "Scenario",
        "line": 14,
        "name": "",
        "tags": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "line": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "line": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "line": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "line": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "",
            "line": 1
          }
        ],
        "steps": [
          {
            "keyword": "Given ",
            "line": 0,
            "match": {
              "location": ""
            },
            "name": "",
            "result": {
              "duration": 17133.4242,
              "error_message": ,
              "status": ""
            }
          }
        ],
    "name": "",
    "uri": ""
  }
]
```

```
[String]$report = Get-Content $inputPath
[System.Object[]]$json = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject "$report"

[String[]]$failedTests = @()

foreach($feature in $json)
{
    foreach($scenario in $feature.elements)
    {
        foreach($step in $scenario.steps)
        {
            if(($scenario.steps).Where({ $step.result.status -eq "Failed" }, 'First').Count -gt 0)
            {
                $failedTests += Generate-FullyQualifiedName $ProjectName $feature.name $scenario.name
                break
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: Your JSON seems to be invalid. Can you correct that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got is pretty much the best way to return multiple "depths" of an object in powershell, since there's not really a .

One improvement is to force powershell to use a `[list[]]` type object instead of the default fixed-length `[System.Array]` created by `$foo = @()`, which has to be destroyed and recreated every time it's extended with `+=`. Instead, try using:

```
$failedTests = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()

# loops...

$failedTests.Add((Generate-FullyQualifiedName -etc))
```

You also don't need to loop through each step either to check if a scenario failed:

```
foreach($scenario in $feature.elements) {
  # -- Skip foreach $step
  if($scenario.steps.result.status -eq 'Failed') {
    $failedTests.Add((Generate-FullyQualifiedName -etc))
  }
}
```

For most purposes, I would stick with the looping you're doing. Depending on how huge each object actually is, it can be a little faster (and uglier) to iterate on an array index int instead of assigning the whole `$feature` object to a variable, but I doubt it would help much here.

Comment: Wow thank you so much that is very helpful, glad to know that was the easiest way. I made a C# application before starting the PS script and in there I was using LINQ selectMany and Where to loop through the nodes. But I was having trouble getting the same results in Powershell glad to know I am doing the correct thing